# Align horizontally with % in CSS

Tags: css, alignment, text-alignment

I've made a sort of diagram with temperature values and a schedule for it. Now I want to align the time-tags perfectly with the middle of my gaps between the "blocks". The first one works with position:absolute and left:(%-px/2), but the second and third example are off. How does one align these boxes?

The Fiddle is [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/gqkt7h82/13/).

```css
body {
  background-color: #DDD;
}

a {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.block {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: .75em;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity, 0.4s ease; /* hover effect transition */
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.block:nth-child(n+2) {
  margin-left: 0.5%;
}

.block:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 3px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.block.cool,
.legend li:nth-of-type(1):before {
  background-color: #41A6F0;
}

.block.hot,
.legend li:nth-of-type(2):before {
  background-color: #E27A3F;
}

.paused.cool {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.paused.hot {
  background-color: #bbb;
}

.barchart {
  display: grid;
  margin: 0;
  grid-template-columns:
    [viewport-start] minmax(0.57em, 1fr) [container-start] minmax(20em, 35em) [container-end] minmax(0.75em, 1fr) [viewport-end];
  grid-auto-rows: 30px;
}

row {
  padding: 5px;
  grid-column: container;
  grid-row: span 4;
  line-height: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 0%;
  animation: expand 1.2s ease forwards;
  /* see animation "expand" below */
}

timerow {
  grid-column: container;
  grid-row: span 1;
  line-height: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  visibility: hidden;
  animation: 1.3s blendin; /* see animation "blendin" below */
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  margin-top: -15px;
  position: relative;
}

timerow a {
  position: absolute;
  height: 25px;
  width: 44px;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  color: #919191;
  background: #fff;
}

/*
timerow a:last-child {
  float: right;
  margin-right: -12px;
}

timerow a:first-child {
  margin-left: -17px;
}
*/
tag {
  grid-column: container;
  padding-top: 8px;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  color: #919191;
}

/* Big-Screen Design */
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .barchart {
    margin-left: -4.5em;
    grid-template-columns:
      [viewport-start] minmax(0.5em, 1fr) [axis-start] minmax(2em, 8em) [container-start] minmax(36em, 3fr) [container-end] minmax(0.5em, 1fr) [viewport-end];
  }

  tag {
    grid-column: axis-start/container-start;
    grid-row: span 4;
    line-height: 120px;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
  }

}

/* intro animation */
@keyframes expand {
  from {
    width: 0%;
  }

  to {
    width: calc(100% - 12px);
  }
}

@keyframes blendin {
  99% {
    visibility: hidden;
  }

  100% {
    visibility: visible;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  @keyframes expand {
    from {
      width: 0%;
    }

    to {
      width: calc(100% - 13px);
    }
  }
}

row:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: .1s;
}

row:nth-child(6) {
  animation-delay: .2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="barchart">
  <tag>Workday</tag>

  <row>
    <a style="width:28.9444444444%;" class="block cool">19deg</a>
    <a style="width:63.805555555%;" class="block hot">21deg</a>
    <a style="width:6.25%;" class="block hot">22deg</a>
  </row>

  <timerow>
  <a style="left:calc(29.1944% - 22px);">07:30</a>
  <a style="left:calc(93.5% - 22px);">22:30</a>
  </timerow>

  <tag>Weekend</tag>
  <row>
    <a style="width:44%;" class="block cool">16deg</a>
    <a style="width:16%;" class="block paused hot">21deg</a>
    <a style="width:38.5%;" class="block paused cool">18deg</a>
  </row>
  
  <timerow>
  <a style="left:calc(44% - 22px);">00:00</a>
<a style="left:calc(60.75% - 22px);">00:00</a>
  </timerow>
  
</div>
```

```
timerow a {
  position: absolute;
  height: 25px;
  width: 44px;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  color: #919191;
  background: #fff;
}
```

this one get's positioned too far right,

```
  <a style="left:calc(93.5% - 22px);">22:30</a>
```

while this one works perfectly, where the ":" is centered in the gap:

```
  <a style="left:calc(29.1944% - 22px);">07:30</a>
```

Even though I added the % numbers and factored in the 0.5% gap and subtracted the 22px for half the width of the box.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also have the padding that you need to account for since `position:absolute` consider the padding-box to do the calculation. Add margin to `timerow` equal to the padding applied to row and you calculation will be correct.

You can also simplify the `-22px` with a translation. Also consider `box-sizing:border-box;` to your row element instead of decreasing the width in the animation.

```css
body {
  background-color: #DDD;
}

a {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.block {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  color: #FFF;
  font-size: .75em;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity, 0.4s ease; /* hover effect transition */
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.block:nth-child(n+2) {
  margin-left: 0.5%;
}

.block:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 3px 10px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.block.cool,
.legend li:nth-of-type(1):before {
  background-color: #41A6F0;
}

.block.hot,
.legend li:nth-of-type(2):before {
  background-color: #E27A3F;
}

.paused.cool {
  background-color: #ccc;
}

.paused.hot {
  background-color: #bbb;
}

.barchart {
  display: grid;
  margin: 0;
  grid-template-columns:
    [viewport-start] minmax(0.57em, 1fr) [container-start] minmax(20em, 35em) [container-end] minmax(0.75em, 1fr) [viewport-end];
  grid-auto-rows: 30px;
}

row {
  padding: 5px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  grid-column: container;
  grid-row: span 4;
  line-height: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 0%;
  animation: expand 1.2s ease forwards;
  /* see animation "expand" below */
}

timerow {
  grid-column: container;
  grid-row: span 1;
  line-height: 14px;
  margin:0 5px;
  text-align: center;
  visibility: hidden;
  animation: 1.3s blendin; /* see animation "blendin" below */
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  margin-top: -15px;
  position: relative;
}

timerow a {
  position: absolute;
  height: 25px;
  width: 44px;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  color: #919191;
  background: #fff;
  transform:translateX(-50%);
}

tag {
  grid-column: container;
  padding-top: 8px;
  font-size: 0.8em;
  color: #919191;
}

/* Big-Screen Design */
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .barchart {
    margin-left: -4.5em;
    grid-template-columns:
      [viewport-start] minmax(0.5em, 1fr) [axis-start] minmax(2em, 8em) [container-start] minmax(36em, 3fr) [container-end] minmax(0.5em, 1fr) [viewport-end];
  }

  tag {
    grid-column: axis-start/container-start;
    grid-row: span 4;
    line-height: 120px;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
  }

}

/* intro animation */
@keyframes expand {
  from {
    width: 0%;
  }

  to {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

@keyframes blendin {
  99% {
    visibility: hidden;
  }

  100% {
    visibility: visible;
  }
}


row:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: .1s;
}

row:nth-child(6) {
  animation-delay: .2s;
}
```

```html
<div class="barchart">
  <tag>Workday</tag>

  <row>
    <a style="width:28.9444444444%;" class="block cool">19deg</a>
    <a style="width:63.805555555%;" class="block hot">21deg</a>
    <a style="width:6.25%;" class="block hot">22deg</a>
  </row>

  <timerow>
  <a style="left:calc((28.9444444444 + 0.5/2)*1%);">07:30</a>
  <a style="left:calc((28.9444444444 + 63.805555555 + 0.5 + 0.5/2)*1%);">22:30</a>
  </timerow>

  <tag>Weekend</tag>
  <row>
    <a style="width:44%;" class="block cool">16deg</a>
    <a style="width:16%;" class="block paused hot">21deg</a>
    <a style="width:38.5%;" class="block paused cool">18deg</a>
  </row>
  
  <timerow>
  <a style="left:calc(44% + 0.5%/2);">00:00</a>
<a style="left:calc(44% + 16% + 0.5% + 0.5%/2);">00:00</a>
  </timerow>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, your answer is awesome. So amazing even, that I would like to make take the last step and make it really useful by positioning relative, such that I can re-use the width on each element, instead of having to sum all the ones before it. Using float: left I get some unexpected line braking going on.

Comment: @mike I would do it with margin like this: https://jsfiddle.net/09nexpjb/ but you still need to account for the width of the previous date each step

Comment: Hey, nice! Basically, that is similar to what I had, except for the width: 0%; -> things I will never understand in CSS. Although, the position is off by a few pixels. Maybe that is because of the calc in % and px? I am coming from C++ -like languages, where stuff like this means a major issue..

Comment: @mike you may always face some rouding issue in CSS since at the end the smallest value is 1px so getting an element off by +/- 1px is logical. if it's a lot bigger then for sure it's something else

Comment: On the second fiddle you kindly wrote for me, the second : is off visuably noticable. I've started having exactly that issue (amongst other smaller ones). I really don't understand what this should come from, since your calculation is as correct as the last one, but if I make the screen super wide (on dual monitors) there is a significant discrepancy in the positioning of the second label for both rows. That is what buggs me. And of course, a roundoff of 1px is acceptable, if it scales correctly, thanks for the reminder.

Comment: @mike can you show me a screenshot? or maybe you have more CSS code involved other than mine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215498/discussion-between-mike-and-temani-afif).

Comment: Just for the reference, Temani Afif provided another great solution involving the relative margins, here: https://jsfiddle.net/4khxcry0/